# Conditional compilation of code based on package version

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, conditionals, matrices

I am working on a document with a colleague and we have different versions of PGF/Tikz installed -- I have version 3 and he has version 2.10. 
This is causing a problem for compilation on our two platforms because the syntax for defining matrices in tikz changed slightly from version 2.1 to 3.0.

(See: [Cannot use custom styled nodes with matrix using Pgf 3.0.0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166969/cannot-use-custom-styled-nodes-with-matrix-using-pgf-3-0-0))

What I would like to do is add code at the beginning of my document which checks the version of pgf/tikz that is being used at compilation. Based on that, I want certain blocks of code to be executed which matches the proper syntax for that version.

Is this possible?

Comment: See _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using/13309 (or search http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=ifpackagelater).

Answer (score 7):

You could define your own conditional, say `\ifTikZVthree` and use

```
\ifTikZVthree
  % <TikZ version 3 stuff>
\else
  % <TikZ version pre-3 stuff>
\fi
```

in your document to define separate version 3/pre-3 stuff. The following minimal example defines `\checkTikZversion` that checks the version of [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) via the macro `\ver@tikz.sty` - defined whenever a package is loaded. In nature, it's very similar to `\@ifpackagelater` (see [Which package version am I using?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)), including discussions in [Detecting which version of the LaTeX format is in use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26178/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\let\@xp\expandafter
\newif\ifTikZVthree
\def\@extractTikZversion#1 v#2 (#3){#2}
\newcommand{\checkTikZversion}{
  \@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\ifnum
    \@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\pdfstrcmp
      \@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp
        {\@xp\@xp\@xp\@extractTikZversion\csname ver@tikz.sty\endcsname}{ 3.0.0}=1
    \TikZVthreetrue
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\checkTikZversion% Check the current TikZ version
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
TikZ version: \@xp\@xp\@xp\strip@prefix\@xp\meaning\csname ver@tikz.sty\endcsname% Show current TikZ version
\makeatother

\ifTikZVthree
  TikZ version: 3.0.0% You are running TikZ version 3.0.0
\else
  Not TikZ version: 3.0.0% You are not running TikZ version 3.0.0
\fi

\end{document}
```

---

Here's how the `\expandafter`/`\@xp`s work within `\checkTikZversion`:

```
\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\ifnum
  \@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\pdfstrcmp
    \@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp\@xp
      {\@xp\@xp\@xp\@extractTikZversion\csname ver@tikz.sty\endcsname}{ 3.0.0}=1
  \TikZVthreetrue
\fi
```

After the first batch of processing `\@xp`s, you're left with

```
\@xp\@xp\@xp\ifnum
  \@xp\@xp\@xp\pdfstrcmp
    \@xp\@xp\@xp
      {\@xp\@extractTikZversion\ver@tikz.sty}{ 3.0.0}=1
  \TikZVthreetrue
\fi
```

where `\ver@tikz.sty` is the expanded construction of `\csname ver@tikz.sty\endcsname`. The second round produces

```
\@xp\ifnum
  \@xp\pdfstrcmp
    \@xp
      {\@extractTikZversion 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)}{ 3.0.0}=1
  \TikZVthreetrue
\fi
```

where `\ver@tikz.sty` has been expanded to the full version of `tikz` (on my machine). The next expansion strips out the version via `\@extractTikZversion`:

```
\ifnum
  \pdfstrcmp
    { 3.0.0}{ 3.0.0}=1
  \TikZVthreetrue
\fi
```

where the actual comparison is made (via e-TeX's `\pdfstrcmp`). Depending on the output, `\ifTikZVthree` is set to either true of false. Note the specific use of space before the version number.

Comment: Instead of `\@xa` you could use the more popular `\@xp`.

Comment: Look ma'! Just one `\expandafter`!

Comment: @Manuel: `\@xp` is specifically defined and used by AMS (defined in [`amsgen.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsgen.dtx). I've updated accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

When you do `\usepackage{tikz}` you have the macro `\pgfversion` available. We actually want to compare the main version number only, so we can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\iftikziii
\begingroup
\def\getmainversion#1.#2\getmainversion{#1}
\ifnum\expandafter\getmainversion\pgfversion\getmainversion=3
  \global\tikziiitrue
\fi
\endgroup

\begin{document}
We have version \iftikziii 3\else 2\fi
\end{document}
```

You can use in your document

```
\iftikziii
   <code for TikZ 3>
\else
   <code for TikZ 2>
\fi
```

If you prefer a double argument (pseudo)conditional, add the code

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tikziiiorii}{%
  \iftikziii
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatletter
```

so the above document can become

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\iftikziii
\begingroup
\def\getmainversion#1.#2\getmainversion{#1}
\ifnum\expandafter\getmainversion\pgfversion\getmainversion=3
  \global\tikziiitrue
\fi
\endgroup
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tikziiiorii}{%
  \iftikziii
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
We have version \tikziiiorii{3}{2}
\end{document}
```

and the general format is

```
\tikziiiorii{<code for version 3>}{<code for version 2>}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first link was exactly what I was looking for:

[Which package version am I using?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using/13309)

There is a LaTeX kernel function `\@ifpackagelater` which serves my purpose by testing the date of a package release:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{tikz}{2013/10/01}
{
 % Code which runs if the package date is 2013/10/01 or later
}
{
 % Code which runs if the package date is older than 2013/10/01
}
\makeatother
```

Thank you for your input!